# Influxdb 2.2 has 'm' after numbers

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have noticed that some of my values in InfluxDB 2.2 have an 'm' character appended to their value. Is there a way to stop this from happening? I am writing my values as floats to the database. This seems to occur for seemingly random values in my dataset. But, the ones that have an 'm' keep it as new data is entered. The values that don't have an 'm' don't seem to ever gain the 'm'.

I am using the python 3 InfluxDB client to write data to the database. Here are the lines that are being written to the database as a batch.

[image]

This picture is showing packV, packC, and packR from left to right.

[image]

Here is the query setup. It is the same for all three in the above picture.

[image]

Comment: "m" could be inserted from the UI? Could you try to export the query result and see whether the output has those "m"  as suffixes?